# How to upload files & database backup on onedrive/skydrive?

Tags: magento-1.9

I want to upload weekly files & database backup zip on onedrive/skydrive
Any extension or code available?

Answer (score 0):

This would be required from a Linux level. Most like a bash script to RSYNC The code away and dump the database and include within the RSYNC.

Likelihood is however skydrive or onedrive don't support SSH based transfers. Consider a more suiting platform such has HiDrive